# How to securily Synchronize selected data from specific tables in a local SQL database with a distant MySQL database

Tags: synchronization, scheduled-tasks, biztalk, distributed-computing, middleware

I am a Linux guy who is lost between the "windows"!

I have an ERP that saves data to a local Windows SQL Server. For some reason we need to periodically synchronize some selected data from specific tables, with a MySQL instance hosted on a distant Windows Server. knowing that the distant MySQL is operated by a Zend2 Web Application.

[image]

According to my knowledge and understanding, the native option I suggest is the following:

Create an API using PHP on the distant server, and submit my data using PUT or POST through a simple script on the local machine, in this case, I need the following:

- Build an API on the distant server
- Configure an extra PHP server on the local Windows Machine.
- Build a small script to call the API providing the selected data.
- handle all the cases of the synchronization process on the distant server.
- Find a Periodic trigger on the local Windows (Something like Linux Cronjob)

This solution seems complicated, and the many layers would result in a big probability of problems, the reason why I am sure there are other ways to do it.

A Windows guy recommended BizTalk as a middle-ware that would handle the local part job, either using a normal API or any other low level interactivity with the distant server.

He also recommended using Windows Tasks as a periodic trigger.

Do you think my solution is the optimal one? if not what do you suggest?!

Comment: Do you already have BizTalk?  Just for such a small task it would be rather expensive in licencing costs.  Have you looked at using SSIS in SQL?  That has both scheduling and the ability to connect to MySQL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would look at a third party tool like DBSync (Not an endorsement) I have used a few different 1 way and 2 way sync tools in the past that create a (master-slave) replication service between different databases.  I'm sure there are some open source solutions as well, but a licensed tool might work best with MSSQL to MySQL.

http://download.cnet.com/DBSync-for-MSSQL-and-MySQL/3000-10254_4-10784422.html

Comment: Thank you, I will check dbSync and come back, but note please that I am not interested in a full replication, only some selected tables or even fields.

Comment: Yeah i get that, that's why I recommended DBSync it looks to allow form syncing of only specific tables.

Comment: Thank you, it's initially what I was looking for. I was surprised also that I can set a scheduel for the tasks using the GUI.

Answer (score 2):

I would consider using a SSIS package as it has both the ability to be scheduled and can connect to MySQL.

BizTalk is an option if you already have that available, it would be rather expensive for just this one job unless there are more integration requirements that you are going to use it for.  BizTalk has the ability to poll the database at regular intervals, so you could use that instead of a scheduled task.

In neither of the above scenarios should you require to configure a local PHP Server.

Comment: Well, I tried to find answers for two questions regarding SSIS:
Is it a commercial solution?! and does it connect to a distant MySQL? if so, do you have any related articles, as the ones I have found talk only about SQL Servers.

Comment: SSIS comes with SQL Server.  It's the standard integration tooling for it, really meant for bulk ETL between databases.